# Interval graph plotting in gnuplot

Tags: graph, gnuplot

I have an equation which goes like this

```
f(x) = x*10 ; 0 < x <= 10
     = x*x + x*10 ; 10 < x < 20
```

How do I plot f(x) in one graph using gnuplot?

Comment: related: several time intervals: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684475/plotting-labeled-intervals-in-matplotlib-gnuplot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
plot [0:20] x <= 10 ? x*10 : x*x + x*10
```

**Update**: if you have more than two functions, you can use this approach:

```
f(x) = x <= 10 ? x \
     : x <= 20 ? x**2 \
     : x <= 40 ? sqrt(x) \
     : x**3
```

and afterwards,

```
plot [0:40] f(x)
```

To clarify, value `f(x)` will be:

- `x` if `x` is equal or less than 10
- `x^2` if `x` is greater than 10 and equal or less than 20
- square root of `x` if `x` is greater than 20 and equal or less than 40
- `x^3` if `x` is greater than 40

Comment: What I did was to write a Python code that generates the values of X and Y and then plot using filename. This approach works great for two intervals. What if there are more than two?