# Plotting labeled intervals in matplotlib/gnuplot

Tags: plot, matplotlib, gnuplot, intervals

I have a data sample which looks like this:

```
a 10:15:22 10:15:30 OK
b 10:15:23 10:15:28 OK
c 10:16:00 10:17:10 FAILED
b 10:16:30 10:16:50 OK
```

What I want is to plot the above data in the following way:

```
captions ^
  |
c |         *------*
b |   *---*    *--*
a | *--*
  |___________________
                     time >
```

With the color of lines depending on the `OK/FAILED` status of the data point. Labels (`a/b/c/...`) may or may not repeat.

As I've gathered from documentation for **gnuplot** and **matplotlib**, this type of a plot should be easier to do in the latter as it's not a standard plot and would require some preprocessing.

The question is:

1. Is there a standard way to do plots like this in any of the tools?
2. If not, how should I go about plotting this data (pointers to relevant tools/documentation/functions/examples which do something-kinda-like the thing described here)?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Updated: Now includes handling the data sample and uses mpl dates functionality.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter, MinuteLocator, SecondLocator
import numpy as np
from StringIO import StringIO
import datetime as dt

### The example data
a=StringIO("""a 10:15:22 10:15:30 OK
b 10:15:23 10:15:28 OK
c 10:16:00 10:17:10 FAILED
b 10:16:30 10:16:50 OK
""")

#Converts str into a datetime object.
conv = lambda s: dt.datetime.strptime(s, '%H:%M:%S')

#Use numpy to read the data in. 
data = np.genfromtxt(a, converters={1: conv, 2: conv},
                     names=['caption', 'start', 'stop', 'state'], dtype=None)
cap, start, stop = data['caption'], data['start'], data['stop']

#Check the status, because we paint all lines with the same color 
#together
is_ok = (data['state'] == 'OK')
not_ok = np.logical_not(is_ok)

#Get unique captions and there indices and the inverse mapping
captions, unique_idx, caption_inv = np.unique(cap, 1, 1)

#Build y values from the number of unique captions.
y = (caption_inv + 1) / float(len(captions) + 1)

#Plot function
def timelines(y, xstart, xstop, color='b'):
    """Plot timelines at y from xstart to xstop with given color."""   
    plt.hlines(y, xstart, xstop, color, lw=4)
    plt.vlines(xstart, y+0.03, y-0.03, color, lw=2)
    plt.vlines(xstop, y+0.03, y-0.03, color, lw=2)

#Plot ok tl black    
timelines(y[is_ok], start[is_ok], stop[is_ok], 'k')
#Plot fail tl red
timelines(y[not_ok], start[not_ok], stop[not_ok], 'r')

#Setup the plot
ax = plt.gca()
ax.xaxis_date()
myFmt = DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(SecondLocator(interval=20)) # used to be SecondLocator(0, interval=20)

#To adjust the xlimits a timedelta is needed.
delta = (stop.max() - start.min())/10

plt.yticks(y[unique_idx], captions)
plt.ylim(0,1)
plt.xlim(start.min()-delta, stop.max()+delta)
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.show()
```

[image: Resulting image]

Comment: Thanks. I've successfully drawn a graph using your solution as a basis. Will accept your answer if no one proposes a better solution.

Comment: I updated my answer, i always wanted to learn the matplotlibs date functionality.

Comment: For different end symbols you replace the vlines with scatter symbols.
plt.scatter(xstart,y,s=100,c=color,marker='x',lw=2,edgecolor=color)

Comment: This example does not work with matplotlib 1.2 (python 2.7, Fedora 19) - it seems that the code is stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: Works for me with matplotlib 1.4.0 Python 2.7 on Mac OS 10.10.

Answer (score 1):

the answer for @tillsten is not working for Python3 any more I did some modification I hope it will helps.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter, MinuteLocator, SecondLocator
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import io

### The example data
a=io.StringIO("""
caption start stop state
a 10:15:22 10:15:30 OK
b 10:15:23 10:15:28 OK
c 10:16:00 10:17:10 FAILED
b 10:16:30 10:16:50 OK""")

data = pd.read_table(a, delimiter=" ")

data["start"] = pd.to_datetime(data["start"])
data["stop"] = pd.to_datetime(data["stop"])

cap, start, stop = data['caption'], data['start'], data['stop']

#Check the status, because we paint all lines with the same color 
#together
is_ok = (data['state'] == 'OK')
not_ok = np.logical_not(is_ok)

#Get unique captions and there indices and the inverse mapping
captions, unique_idx, caption_inv = np.unique(cap, 1, 1)

#Build y values from the number of unique captions.
y = (caption_inv + 1) / float(len(captions) + 1)

#Plot function
def timelines(y, xstart, xstop, color='b'):
    """Plot timelines at y from xstart to xstop with given color."""   
    plt.hlines(y, xstart, xstop, color, lw=4)
    plt.vlines(xstart, y+0.03, y-0.03, color, lw=2)
    plt.vlines(xstop, y+0.03, y-0.03, color, lw=2)

#Plot ok tl black    
timelines(y[is_ok], start[is_ok], stop[is_ok], 'k')
#Plot fail tl red
timelines(y[not_ok], start[not_ok], stop[not_ok], 'r')

#Setup the plot
ax = plt.gca()
ax.xaxis_date()
myFmt = DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(SecondLocator(interval=20)) # used to be SecondLocator(0, interval=20)

#To adjust the xlimits a timedelta is needed.
delta = (stop.max() - start.min())/10

plt.yticks(y[unique_idx], captions)
plt.ylim(0,1)
plt.xlim(start.min()-delta, stop.max()+delta)
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

**gnuplot 5.2 version with creating a unique key list**

The main difference to @CiroSantilli's solution is that a list of unique keys is created automatically from column 1 and the index can be accessed via the defined function `Lookup()`. The referenced gnuplot demo already uses a list of unique items, however, in the OP's case there are duplicates.

Creating such a list of unique items does not exist in gnuplot right away, so you have to implement it yourself.
The code requires gnuplot >=5.2. It is probably difficult to get a solution which works under gnuplot 4.4 (the time of OP's question) because a few useful features were not implemented at that time: `do for`-loops, `summation`, datablocks, ... (a version for gnuplot 4.6 might be possible with some workarounds).

**Edit:** the earlier version used `with vectors` and `linewidth 20` to plot the bars, however, `linewidth 20` also extends in x-direction which is not desired here. Therefore, `with boxxyerror` is now used.

---

Yes, it can be done shorter and clearer.

**Script:**

```
### Time chart with gnuplot (requires gnuplot>=5.0)
reset session

$Data <<EOD
# category        start      end        status
"event 1"         10:15:22   10:15:30   OK
"event 2"         10:15:23   10:15:28   OK
pause             10:16:00   10:17:10   FAILED
"something else"  10:16:30   10:17:50   OK
unknown           10:17:30   10:18:50   OK
"event 3"         10:18:30   10:19:50   FAILED
pause             10:19:30   10:20:50   OK
"event 1"         10:17:30   10:19:20   FAILED
EOD

# create list of unique items
uniqueList = ''
item(col)           = ' "'.strcol(col).'"'
isInList(list,col)  = strstrt(uniqueList,item(col))  # returns a number >0 if found
addToList(list,col) = list.item(col)
stats $Data u (!isInList(uniqueList,1) ? uniqueList = addToList(uniqueList,1) : 0) nooutput

timeCenter(col1,col2) = (timecolumn(col1,myTimeFmt)+timecolumn(col2,myTimeFmt))*0.5 
timeDeltaT(col1,col2) = (timecolumn(col1,myTimeFmt)-timecolumn(col2,myTimeFmt))*0.5 
Lookup(col)           = int(sum [i=1:words(uniqueList)] (strcol(col) eq word(uniqueList,i)) ? i : 0)
myColor(col)          = strcol(col) eq "OK" ? 0x00cc00 : 0xff0000
myBoxWidth            = 0.6

myTimeFmt = "%H:%M:%S"
set format x "%M:%S" timedate
set yrange [0.5:words(uniqueList)+0.5]
set grid x,y

plot $Data u (timeCenter(2,3)):(Lookup(1)):(timeDeltaT(2,3)):(0.5*myBoxWidth): \
             (myColor(4)):ytic(1) w boxxyerror fill solid 1.0 lc rgb var notitle
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

**gnuplot `with vector` solution**

Minimized from: http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.2/gantt.html

main.gnuplot

```
#!/usr/bin/env gnuplot

$DATA << EOD
1 1 5
1 11 13
2 3 10
3 4 8
4 7 13
5 6 15
EOD

set terminal png size 512,512
set output "main.png"
set xrange [-1:]
set yrange [0:]
unset key
set border 3
set xtics nomirror
set ytics nomirror
set style arrow 1 nohead linewidth 3
plot $DATA using 2 : 1 : ($3-$2) : (0.0) with vector as 1, \
     $DATA using 2 : 1 : 1 with labels right offset -2
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/gnuplot-cheat/blob/b8ebf45e2092394fd2af8ee933a001e6eba06ea2/intervals.gnuplot).

Output:

[image]

You can remove the labels by removing the second `plot` command line, I added them because they are useful in many applications to more easily identify the intervals.

The Gantt example I linked to shows how to handle date formats instead of integers.

Tested in gnuplot 5.2 patchlevel 2, Ubuntu 18.04.