# Matplotlib hangs when plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot some datetime objects in Python with Matplotlib, [just as I have seen at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684475/plotting-labeled-intervals-in-matplotlib-gnuplot).

But when it gets to the savefig call, it gets stuck. This is my code:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg')  # Matplotlib backend to use without an X-server
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter, MinuteLocator
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

def plot_scenario(outages_start, outages_end, prediction_start, prediction_end,
    filepath=None):

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    y = [0.3, 0.7]
    timelines(ax, y[0], prediction_start, prediction_end, color='r')
    for xstart, xstop in zip(outages_start, outages_end):
        timelines(ax, y[1], xstart, xstop)

    ax.xaxis_date()
    myFmt = DateFormatter('%d %H:%M')
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MinuteLocator(0, interval=15))

    # Delta needed to adjust the xlimits
    delta = (prediction_end - prediction_start) / 10

    #ax.set_yticks(['Prediction', 'Outages'])  #Not working
    ax.set_ylim(0, 1)
    ax.set_xlim(prediction_start - delta, prediction_end + delta)
    ax.set_xlabel('Time')

    if filepath is None:
        fig.show()
    else:
        # Save plot as PNG
        fig.savefig(filepath) # Gets stuck here
        print 'PGN file saved at ' + filepath


# plot timelines at y from xstart to xstop with a given color
def timelines(current_axis, y, xstart, xstop, color='b'):
    current_axis.hlines(y, xstart, xstop, color, lw=4)
    current_axis.vlines(xstart, y+0.03, y-0.03, color, lw=2)
    current_axis.vlines(xstop, y+0.03, y-0.03, color, lw=2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    prediction_start = datetime(2014, 3, 20) + timedelta(hours=12)
    prediction_end = prediction start + timedelta(hours=10)
    outages_start = []
    outages_end = []
    outages_start.append(datetime(2014, 3, 20) + timedelta(hours=14))
    outages_end.append(datetime(2014, 3, 20) + timedelta(hours=15))
    outages_start.append(datetime(2014, 3, 20) + timedelta(hours=17))
    outages_end.append(datetime(2014, 3, 20) + timedelta(hours=18))

    path = '/home/myuser/test.png'
    plot_scenario(outages_start, outages_end, prediction_start, prediction_end, path)
```

I'm using Agg since I'm working without X-server into an Ubuntu Server machine, but this can't be the problem because I made a simple range plot and the figure was saved correctly, so I must be making some mistake at the code.

Any help?

Comment: Can you try to reduce the amount of code here?  Without the ability to reproduce your problem there isn't much anyone can do to help you.

Comment: It is currently a small code, just the main is missing, so I don't know what the problem is, or why I'm deserving a downvote. I'll add the main anyway

Comment: The problem isn't length, it is that it is not runnable.  http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: And you got a down vote because you have enough rep to know better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem is in the line:

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MinuteLocator(0, interval=15))
```

But I don't really know why. Commenting that line, the code works.