# labeled intervals in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm making a reference to the question on [Plotting labeled intervals in matplotlib/gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684475/plotting-labeled-intervals-in-matplotlib-gnuplot/37159537#37159537), the problem with the solution exposed there, is that doesn't work with only one line of data in the files. This is the code I'm trying:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter, MinuteLocator, SecondLocator
import numpy as np
from StringIO import StringIO
import datetime as dt

a=StringIO("""MMEX 2016-01-29T12:38:22 2016-01-29T12:39:03 SUCCESS 
""")

#Converts str into a datetime object.
conv = lambda s: dt.datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')

#Use numpy to read the data in. 
data = np.genfromtxt(a, converters={1: conv, 2: conv},
                 names=['caption', 'start', 'stop', 'state'], dtype=None)
cap, start, stop = data['caption'], data['start'], data['stop']

#Check the status, because we paint all lines with the same color 
#together
is_ok = (data['state'] == 'SUCCESS')
not_ok = np.logical_not(is_ok)

#Get unique captions and there indices and the inverse mapping    
captions, unique_idx, caption_inv = np.unique(cap, 1, 1)

#Build y values from the number of unique captions.
y = (caption_inv + 1) / float(len(captions) + 1)

#Plot function
def timelines(y, xstart, xstop, color='b'):
    """Plot timelines at y from xstart to xstop with given color."""   
    plt.hlines(y, xstart, xstop, color, lw=4)
    plt.vlines(xstart, y+0.005, y-0.005, color, lw=2)
    plt.vlines(xstop, y+0.005, y-0.005, color, lw=2)

#Plot ok tl black    
timelines(y[is_ok], start[is_ok], stop[is_ok], 'k')
#Plot fail tl red
timelines(y[not_ok], start[not_ok], stop[not_ok], 'r')

#Setup the plot
ax = plt.gca()
ax.xaxis_date()
myFmt = DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(SecondLocator(interval=3600)) # used to be         SecondLocator(0, interval=20)

#To adjust the xlimits a timedelta is needed.
delta = (stop.max() - start.min())/10

plt.yticks(y[unique_idx], captions)
plt.ylim(0,1)
plt.xlim(start.min()-delta, stop.max()+delta)
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.xticks(rotation=70)
plt.show(block=True)
```

When I try this code, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./testPlot.py", line 49, in <module>
    timelines(y[is_ok], start[is_ok], stop[is_ok], 'k')
ValueError: boolean index array should have 1 dimension
```

Also, when I try to add a dummy line on the data, let's said "MMEX 2016-01-01T00:00:00 2016-01-01T00:00:00 SUCCESS", the plot works but doesn't look good.

Any suggestions? I tried to put this question on the same post when I found the solution, but I don't have enough reputation...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give the outputs of `shape(y)`, `shape(start)`, `shape(stop)` and `shape(is_ok)`? I suppose your data arrays don't have the same dimension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that when you only read 1 item with `np.genfromtxt`, it is producing scalars (0-dimensions). We need them to be at least 1D.

You can add these lines just above where you define your `timelines` function, and then everything works ok.

This makes use of the `numpy` function [`np.atleast_1d()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.atleast_1d.html), to turn the scalars into 1D `numpy` arrays.

```
#Check the dimensions are at least 1D (for 1-item data input)
if start.ndim < 1:
    start = np.atleast_1d(start)
if stop.ndim < 1::
    stop = np.atleast_1d(stop)    
if is_ok.ndim < 1:
    is_ok = np.atleast_1d(is_ok)    
if not_ok.ndim < 1:
    not_ok = np.atleast_1d(is_ok)
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks VERY much! it works! Now, I'm posting the solution (linked to this page) on the original post so if anyone has the same error, He/she can find the answer.

Comment: well, the admins keep deleting my responses on the original post. Hope if someone has the same issue, somehow get the solution

Comment: If this solved your issue you might consider accepting the answer

Comment: OK, I clicked on the "check" image and turn green.... this means that I accept it? I'm pretty much new here....