# Gnuplot start to end position as x

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data file test.tsv which consists of three columns:

letter  start  end

a      15    20

a      40    60

b      124   171

b      237   316

I set y axis to represent the a and b, How can I get lines cover start to end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a more general case you could do the following which is similar to [the solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56713296/7295599).

1. Create a list of unique keys and use those as the y-axis tics/labels.
2. Define a lookup function and plot the data accordingly.

You can use the plotting style `with vectors` but if you want thicker bars instead of lines, I would use the plotting style `with boxxyerror` because thicker lines also extend in line direction.

**Code:**

```
### Schedule plot
reset session

$Data <<EOD
# category  start    end
"a task"  15   20
"b task"  40   60
"c task"  124 171
"d task"  237 316
"c task"   30  35
"a task"  111 197
"d task"   95 103
"b task"   80  93
"special"  10 100
EOD

# create list of unique keys
KeyList = ''
set table $Dummy
    plot $Data u (Key='"'.strcol(1).'"', strstrt(KeyList,Key) ? \
    NaN : KeyList=KeyList.Key." ") w table
unset table

# define function for lookup
Lookup(s) = (Index = NaN, sum [i=1:words(KeyList)] \
    (Index = s eq word(KeyList,i) ? i : Index,0), Index)

set yrange [0.5:words(KeyList)+0.5]

plot $Data u 2:(Index=Lookup(strcol(1))):($3-$2):(0):(Index): \
     ytic(word(KeyList,Index)) w vector nohead lw 4 lc var notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]